# Linux bash - reprint user's input

Tags: linux, bash

I have an old shell script which needs to be moved to bash. This script prints progress of some activity and waits for user's commands. If no action is taken by user for 15 seconds screen is redrawn with new progress and timer starts again. Here's my problem:

I am trying to use `read -t 15 myVar` - this way after 15 seconds of waiting loop will be restarted. There is however a scenario which brings me a problem:

- screen redrawn and script waits for input (prints '`Enter command:`')
- user enters `foo` but doesn't press <kbd>enter</kbd>
- after 15 seconds screen is again redrawn and script waits for input - note, that `foo` is not displayed anywhere on the screen (prints '`Enter command:`')
- user enters `bar` and presses <kbd>enter</kbd>

At this moment variable `$myVar` holds '`foobar`'.

What do I need? I am looking for a way to find the first string typed by user, so I could redisplay it after refreshing status. This way user will see:
`Enter command: foo`

On Solaris I could use `stty -pendin` to save input into some sort of a buffer, and after refresh run `stty pendin` to get this input from buffer and print it on a screen.

Is there a Linux equivalent to `stty pendin` feature? Or maybe you know some bash solution to my problem?

Comment: To clarify, do you require that after 15 seconds the screen be redrawn? Why?

Comment: Yes, I need the screen to be redrawn every 15 seconds. This script controls progress of some procedure being performed on server. With each redraw user will see how it's progressing. Without timeout user would have to press enter from time to time to see changes, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I have the solution. I took nhed's proposition and worked a bit on it :)

The main code prints some status and waits for input:

```
while :
do
    # print the progress on the screen
    echo -n "Enter command: "
    tput sc # save the cursor position
    echo -n "$tmpBuffer" # this is buffer which holds typed text (no 'ENTER' key yet)
    waitForUserInput
    read arguments <<< $(echo $mainBuffer) # this buffer is set when user presses 'ENTER'
    mainBuffer="" # don't forget to clear it after reading
    # now do the action requested in $arguments
done
```

Function waitForUserInput waits 10 seconds for a keypress. If nothing typed - exits, but already entered keys are saved in a buffer. If key is pressed, it is parsed (added to buffer, or removed from buffer in case of backspace). On Enter buffer is saved to another buffer, from which it is read for further processing:

```
function waitForUserInput {
    saveIFS=$IFS # save current IFS
    IFS="" # change IFS to empty string, so 'ENTER' key can be read

    while :
    do
        read -t10 -n1 char
        if (( $? == 0 ))
        then
            # user pressed something, so parse it
            case $char in
                $'\b')
                    # remove last char from string with sed or perl
                    # move cursor to saved position with 'tput rc'
                    echo -n "$tmpBuffer"
                    ;;
                "")
                    # empty string is 'ENTER'
                    # so copy tmpBuffer to mainBuffer
                    # clear tmpBuffer and return to main loop
                    IFS=$saveIFS
                    return 0
                    ;;
                 *)
                    # any other char - add it to buffer
                    tmpBuffer=$tmpBuffer$char
                    ;;
            esac
        else
            # timeout occured, so return to main function
            IFS=$saveIFS
            return 1
        fi
    done
}
```

Thanks to all of you for your help!

Comment: FYI, you don't need to save and restore IFS. Take a look at my answer for how to call `read` with a temporary IFS. Also, don't forget to quote expansions!

Answer (score 2):

I guess one way would be to manually accumulate the user input ... use `read` with `-n1` so that it returns after every character, then you can add it to your string.  To prevent excessive drawing you would have to calculate how many remaining seconds are on the 15 second clock ...

---

Addendum:

For your comment about space/return - you basically want to use an IFS without the characters you want, such as space

example:

```
XIFS="${IFS}"  # backup IFS
IFS=$'\r'      # use a character your user is not likely to enter (or just the same but w/o the space)


# Enter will look like en empty string
$ read -n1 X; echo --; echo -n "${X}" | od -tx1

--
0000000


# space will be presented as a character
$ read -n1 X; echo --; echo -n "${X}" | od -tx1
 --
0000000 20
0000001


# after you are all done, you probably wantto restore the IFS
IFS="${XIFS}"
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that this will be the best approach. I am working on solution like you described, but I've hit another wall - I need to correctly treat 'space' and 'enter' (spaces are allowed in commands). However bash claims that both 'space' and 'enter' are empty string when read with 'read -n1' - any idea why?

Comment: @PatrykBaranowski Can you try to change the IFS?  (just a guess)

Comment: @PatrykBaranowski see expanded my answer to address your last comment

Comment: this is what I needed! I changed IFS to empty string. After this change read treats 'space' as any other char and 'enter' as only empty string. Thanks!

Comment: It's not necessary to back up and restore IFS, simply prefix `IFS=$'\r'` to each `read` command. In addition, if you say `IFS= read -d '' -n 1 X` then read will capture space, newline and anything else. There's no need to use a 'magic' value for IFS.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what @nhed was saying, perhaps something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=5

draw_screen () {
    clear;
    echo "Elapsed time: $SECONDS" # simulate progress indicator
    printf 'Enter command: %s' "$1"
}

increment=$limit
str=
end=0
while ! [ $end -eq 1 ] ; do
    draw_screen "$str"
    while [ $SECONDS -lt $limit ] && [ $end -eq 0 ] ; do
            c=
            IFS= read -t $limit -r -n 1 -d '' c
            if [ "$c" = $'\n' ] ; then
                    end=1
            fi
            str="${str}${c}"
    done
    let limit+=increment
done
str="${str%$'\n'}" # strip trailing newline

echo "input was: '$str'"
```

The solution is not ideal:

- You can sometimes be typing in the middle of the loop and mess up input
- You can't edit anything nicely (but this is fixable with a lot more work)

But maybe it's enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Bash 4:

```
read -p 'Enter something here: ' -r -t 15 -e -i "$myVar" myVar
```

The `-e` turns on readline support for the user's text entry. The `-i` uses the following text as the default contents of the input buffer which it displays to the user. The following text in this case is the previous contents of the variable you're reading into.

Demonstration:

```
$ myVar='this is some text'    # simulate previous entry
$ read -p 'Enter something here: ' -r -t 15 -e -i "$myVar" myVar
Enter something here: this is some text[]
```

Where `[]` represents the cursor. The user will be able to backspace and correct the previous text, if needed.

Comment: Denis, thanks for proposition. Sadly code will have to work both in bash3 and bash4. Besides, this does not cover case described in initial question - when user types something but doesn't press 'ENTER' key, then $myVar is empty.